# Has anyone updated their bootcamp win7 to win10?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, software-update

As the title states has anyone successfully updated their bootcamp install of windows from 7 to 10 with the windows update tool? Is it useable? Do the drivers work? Does it mess up the bootloader?

Comment: I was not successful, not sure why, still analyzing. If you try let me know, and make sure you have a back up to recover.

Comment: I'm having a go now. Had a problem with the 'Something happened error' (for anyone reading this: you need to change your language to English (US) in both the Language and Region, and the Language and Region Administrative Tab settings).

Not sure why this question is attracting downvotes?

Comment: I had my on English already :(

Comment: That's annoying . Mine got through to about 20% installed and then quit for no apparent reason, stating that the install had failed. 

Not sure why...

Comment: there is an Article on theverge.com about doing just that. they mention it is not yet officially supported and YMMV but otherwise it worked for them.

Comment: I succeed in preforming a clean install of Windows 10 Pro 64 bit on my iMac 20 inch mid 2007. I used the "Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033". I had to leave the computer disconnected from the internet until the Boot Camp Support Software was installed. This meant I had to boot to Audit mode and install the Boot Camp software before creating my user account. The Device Manager shows not problems with the drivers or hardware.

Comment: I've finally got around to having another crack at this. Worked like a charm. I had my english settings changed from back when I tried it the first time. I just downloaded the install tool from the link above, and let windows do the rest. Everything works perfectly so far! + Win10 can actually drive a retina display properly. Looks great!